# How do I increase maximum download size in an MVC application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, download, out-of-memory, iis-8

I am frankly stumped. This is beyond my experience.

I have a C# MVC program that generates a zip file in a MemoryStream for downloading.  The action method is called by a button click to JavaScript.

The only problem is that in some cases the potential file size can easily exceed one Gig and from my reading, that is a common problem.  I've tried upping the Maximum Allowed Content Length to 3000000000 in Request Filtering on IIS (IIS8).  I've tried adding requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength to my web.config.  *I've even tried breaking up the zip through multiple calls to the action method (without success), although I have yet to get any confirmation/denial that this is even possible.*

Is there any setting within IIS or my web.config that I could be overlooking?  Could this be a company network issue, not solvable on an app developer's level?

Comment: Although you failed to mention the exact issue you're encountering, based on the tags on your question, I'm assuming you're running out of memory. There is no solution for that aside from putting more RAM on your server. There is no inherent download limit, but if you're creating something in memory, obviously it cannot be larger than the available memory of the system.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that you'll also need to account for multiple requests. If you're create a 1GB file, for example, adding 1GB of additional memory only helps a single request. If two people try to access the same action that creates that 1GB file, then you'll need 2GB of RAM to satisfy both requests. Caching the created file to the filesystem would help as you'd only need the memory for the initial creation, but you should ensure you have plenty of headroom above the average file size.

Comment: I've requested more memory from management (but I'm not holding my breath...)  It's got 8 gig already.

Comment: 8GB is nothing for even a moderately large website. I've got a site sitting on 32 GB and doesn't even do much explicitly in memory (i.e. this is memory just for the thread pools of the workers). Granted, we serve 1M+ uniques a month, but even that is relatively tame compared to many sites.

Comment: A quick rule of thumb is that each worker process should have at least 2-4 GB, and you should have one worker per discrete CPU core. However, that's just the base operating RAM, if you are explicitly doing stuff in memory, then you'll need additional RAM for that. And don't forget the OS itself, which will sit on 2-4 GB of RAM out of the box. In other words, if you've got a single worker process, you might need as much as 8GB just to handle standard requests, let alone doing additional work in memory.

Comment: Ok.  No new memory.  We decided to initialize the MemoryStream capacity instead.

This was no improvement.  We arbitrarily set the initial size to 2000000000 (which should be more than enough).  Incidentally, this is all running on a Windows Server 2012 machine. 

All this time I had the task manager performance screen up and everything appeared fine right up to the crash.  Apparently enough memory.  Since I turned off the custom errors I got a 'Overflow or underflow in the arithmetic operation.' message.  (I did have to go into the task manager and kill a probable orphan process.)

Comment: Not sure I understand. Initializing the MemoryStream is actually kind of worse. You'll still have issues when the thing you're creating is larger than what you initialized, but now you're ensuring that even things that you create that don't need that much memory consume far more than they need. Out of memory is out of memory. It doesn't matter if you initialize the MemoryStream first or not.

Comment: If you can't get more memory for the server, you should offload tasks like this somewhere else. For example, you could run a script to create the zip files on some other machine and then transfer them to your web server. That way, you don't need to engage the extra memory on the web server itself.

Comment: Not sure I understand either.  My boss ordered me to,  He seemed to think it would simplify memory management.  So exactly how is it 'kind of worse'?  Can you provide any reference links?  (Clearly I'm on a learning curve...)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so it's kind of hard to explain big concepts in 400 characters or less, so I think I'm just causing more confusion sticking in the comments section. Besides, I think we're close enough here to an "answer" as you're likely to get.

The default constructor of `MemoryStream` essentially sets the initial size to 0. In reality, the initial size is set to somewhere around 256, but since the initial size is mostly a guide, and it doesn't actually claim that space until its needed, it starts at 0.

Each time you write to the stream, it checks how much is being written versus the remaining size of the buffer array. If it can't fit the write, it creates a new, larger buffer array and copies the old buffer array into that. In this way, setting an initial size *can* help somewhat, in that you start off with a larger initial buffer array and you may not need to grow that buffer. You *might* have a better chance of getting a contiguous block of memory, which I'll explain the importance of in a bit, but that actually kind of works against you, as well. If you only need 1MB for the file, but you're initializing with 100MB *and* there's not 100MB of contiguous memory, you'll get an `OutOfMemoryException`, even though there might be 1MB of contiguous memory available.

Regardless of whether you initialize or not, there remains certain immutable facts. First, `MemoryStream` requires contiguous memory. Even if you technically have memory available on the system, it's possible you might not have *large blocks of available memory*. In other words if you have 4GB available, but it's all fragmented, even trying to create a 1GB stream in memory could fail, simply because it can't reserve 1GB of *contiguous* memory. Obviously, the larger the file you're tying to create in memory, the greater the chances that you're going to run into this issue. **For this reason alone, I would say you're out of luck without raising the amount of system RAM**. With 8GB and probably only 4-6GB actually available to IIS and then split up between worker processes and threads, the odds that you're going to be able to claim 25% or so of the available RAM as contiguous space, is highly unlikely.

The next immutable fact may or may not be relevant, but since you haven't specified, I'll mention it. If your web app is deployed as 32-bit, you'll have a hard limit of 2GB for *any* object, meaning a `MemoryStream` could never house more than 2GB (actually around 1.3-1.6GB as .NET code consumes some of that address space), and any attempt to make it do so will result in an `OutOfMemoryException`, even if you had some ridiculous amount of RAM on the system like 1TB+. If your app is 64-bit, this is less likely an issue as you can address a ton more memory, assuming it's compiled properly. You'd have to pretty much try to screw that up, though, so you should be fine.

Finally, multiple writes can cause an issue as well. As I said previously, the buffer array resizes (if necessary) in response to writes. Each time it resizes, the new buffer array must *also* be able to fit in contiguous address space. As a result, multiple resizes can cause you to bump into an `OutOfMemoryException` you wouldn't have hit if you had written all the data from the start. This is where initializing the `MemoryStream` can be helpful, but as I said before, it's also a double-edged sword, as your initial buffer size might be too great to begin with and you end up with an exception where you may have not had one letting it grow organically. Long and short, try to write everything to the stream in one go rather than piecemeal.

Comment: Just to clarify, the app is compiled with Target = Any CPU.  However the server this runs on is 64 bit and the app pool it runs in has Enable 32 Bit Applications = False.  So I think I'm OK on that part.   As for writing everything to the stream at one go, please clarify.  The process is essentially a loop which adds one file at a time.  Not sure I see any other way to do it.

Comment: Complete failure so far.  My boss upped memory to 16Gig.  I then tried my program both with and without initialization of the MemoryStream size.  Same 'arithmetic' error both times.

Comment: Another thing:  The first error message on the stack trace is: [HttpException (0x80004005): An error occurred while communicating with the remote host. The error code is 0x80070216.]
   System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.RaiseCommunicationError(Int32 result, Boolean throwOnDisconnect)    IIS7?  The server is running IIS8.

Comment: I've also tried adding maxQueryStringLength to the system.web setting  <httpRuntime executionTimeout="3600" maxQueryStringLength="2097152" />   Again no luck.